# Demographic Report Data in FB Ads API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

Is it possible to access the demographic report data in the Facebook Ads API? If so, how do I do it? If not, why not? Will it be possible soon? I have clients who would really like to have access to this data through our system. It's such valuable information, I can't imagine why it hasn't been added to the API yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a API update coming soon for this? Facebook is updating the reporting tools for ads http://screencast.com/t/QupFDNH88vbm; and the data is really easy for the clients to view on their accounts but not from our system as there seems to be no API input for demographic data. I am expecting to see demographic data in the following docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think that the only way to get the data is via the reports downloaded via the interface.

It will be great to have this functionality via API, because the scheduled reports are not working anymore.